# Adding classes to an ASP.NET MVC4 project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

In an ASP.NET MVC4 project, I have a subdirectory called App_Code (manually created). It contains .cs files with classes in them. I use these classes in several different .cshtml files. The .cshtml files compile and work as expected.

My classes are in a namespace:

```
namespace Foo {
    public class Bar {
        //  ... properties
    }
}
```

I want to use one of these classes in a controller:

```
using System;
// ...
using Foo;

namespace MyProject.Controllers
{
    public class MyController {
        Foo.Bar SelectedBar { get; set; }
    }
}
```

When I do this, I get a compiler error:

```
Error   3   The type or namespace name 'Foo' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

If I move the .cs files to the Controllers directory, then the .cshtml classes can't "see" them instead.

How do you add classes to a MVC4 project? Should I be creating a second project?

I've been doing C# for years now, but it's all been Windows Forms and XAML. With ASP.NET I'm on the learning curve like a rhino on skates.

Comment: Something very odd is going on with your project if your Views can "see" code just because it's in App_Data.  They should only have access to namespaces specified in the <namespaces> element of the web.config in your Views folder.  Similarly, your controllers should have access to all the code in your project, even if it's in a previously special folder name like App_Code.  Did this project start its life as a non-MVC site?

Comment: @Dave I just created the project yesterday. I added the namespace to the top-level web.config but not the one in Views. Which I wasn't even aware of. Derp. Not that it would have made any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`App_Code` is used by plain old ASP.NET Web Forms **Web Site** project. When you place your classes there they're compiled by ASP.NET (not by Visual Studio like in MVC project). In a Web Site project you're basically exposing your code-files and the ASP.NET does the compilation for you. When using MVC you cannot create a Web Site project but instead you create a Project which is compiled before deployed.

If you want to use this directory in MVC project (not preferred) you can right click on files in `App_Code` and change Build Action from `Content` to `Compile`. (This way when you compile your MVC project the files from this directory will be taken and compiled into a .dll inside the `bin` directory).

Second and probably more preferred way is to organize your files differently. For example, in a typical project you might have such directories as `/Infrastructure` and `/Models`. You can add a separate Class Library project for you Business Logic Layer and so on.

Comment: I am enlightened! Thank you kindly.

Answer (score 5):

I am assuming it is a model object and you can add them to the Model folder from within your project.

If you want to make your project more scalable you can create a separate c# library project and add a reference to your MVC app.